# Почему не обособляется причастный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

> Но помимо этой горькой нервности слезы вызывающей подчас...

Почему *слезы вызывающей подчас* не выделяется?

Comment: А что дальше-то? Какое продолжение? Имея только этот обрывок, совершенно не скажешь, что запятая не нужна.

Comment: Я прочитал "слезЫ" (р. п.). А надо "слёзы", что ли?

Comment: А я прочитал (мысленно пристроив запятую, которой явно где-то не хватает, после "слезы"), что _горькая нервность слезы подчас вызывает (нечто)_. Так что придётся подыскать место для знаков. Другой вариант понимания: "_эта горькая (после неё зпт) подчас вызывает нервности слезы, а помимо неё..."_

Comment: @Alex_ander, не знаю, насколько "явно" там не хватает запятой, но в остальном я полностью солидарен. Читать, если не знать первоисточника, можно десятком разных способов. И они требуют разного пунктуационного оформления.

Answer (score 1):

И так и так можно. 
Тут надо у автора спрашивать, что он имел в виду. В большинстве интернет-источников, включая достаточно авторитетные, этот текст идет без запятой, а бумажного издания у меня нету.

Все зависит от того, к чему относится "помимо нервности".

(1) Если к самому причастному "помимо нервности вызывающей слёзы", то обособление оборота с "помимо" факультативно - и лучше без него.

(2) А вот если "помимо нервности... сколько (есть всего)", то причастный оборот, естественно ограничивается "слезы... подчас" - и требует неукоснительного обособления.

Честно говоря, мне (как и Римме Михайловой) понимание (2) куда ближе. В прочтении (1) фраза какая-то неполноценная, усеченная. Но с другой стороны, если понимать как (2), то "помимо ..." становится развернутым уточнением, его имеет смысл обособить.

То есть при таком понимании я бы оформил так.

***Но, помимо этой горькой нервности,

слёзы вызывающей подчас,

сколько в вас возвышенности, нежности,

сколько героического в вас!***

Comment: Вопрос-то был, собственно, об обособлении причастного оборота _слезы вызывающей подчас._ Он ведь выделяется запятыми в любом случае.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  *об обособлении причастного оборота* Если известно, что это ***весь*** причастный оборот, то зачем спрашивать? *К директору Ивановой, помимо Петрова **вызывающей подчас Сидорова**, на сей раз вызвали Смирнова*   - почему не обособляется "причастный оборот"?!

Answer (score 0):

Причастный оборот стоит после определяемого слова — он обособляется [по общим правилам](https://lampa.io/p/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-00000000320b2387f51b662265394613). (При обычном порядке слов: помимо нервности, вызывающей подчас слёзы.)

*Но помимо этой горькой **нервности,

слёзы вызывающей подчас,**

сколько в вас возвышенности, нежности,

сколько героического в вас!*
[Е. Евтушенко. Женщинам](https://litlife.club/books/224464/read?page=11)